# alias to turn on/off openvpn

Tags: bash, openvpn, alias, bashrc

I do have a list of `*.ovpn` configuration inside the directory of `/etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/`

inside that directory i do have a bash script called `go`

include the following code which will pickup random server from the list and connect to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -- *.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
shift $(( RANDOM % $# ))
openvpn "$1"
```

I tried to create alias to call the script by the following.

```
alias vpn='bash /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/go'
```

But it's keep giving me an error

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: *.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
Use --help for more information.
```

But if i call it by the following alias so it's will run without any issue.

```
alias vpn='cd /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/ && bash go'
```

Usually i open `screen` session to connect to the `vpn` and then detached it and once I'm done so i reattach to it and then use `CTRL + C` to cancel the `vpn` connection.

What I'm looking for is to set `2` aliases

1- alias to turn on the vpn without needing to open `screen` session or busy the current terminal and once the vpn connected i want to make sure it's connected by calling `curl ifconfig.co` to view the `IP`.

2- alias to turn off the vpn.

---

***NOTE***:

**Are it's possible to prevent the `alias` which turn on the vpn to run in case if if we are already connected to VPN?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use full path in `set` command
- run `screen` in [detached mode](https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach)
- use a `case ... esac` construct to make a start/stop script.

Maybe something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

start(){
  status # Print IP before connection
  set -- /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/*.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
  shift $(( RANDOM % $# ))
  screen -S vpn -dm openvpn "$1" # connect
  sleep 5 # wait for connection
  status # Print IP after connection
}
stop(){
  screen -S vpn -X quit
  pkill -f ovpn
}
status(){
  printf 'IP: %s\n' "$(curl -s ifconfig.co)"
}

case "$1" in
start)
    if screen -ls | grep -w vpn; then
      echo "Vpn already connected";
      status
    else
      start
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
*)
    status
    ;;
esac
```

and then you can add this as an alias:

```
alias vpn='bash /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/go'
```

Usage:

```bsh
# Start connection
vpn start

# Stop connection
vpn stop

# get status
vpn
```

---

As an alternative to an alias, you can put the script in your `~/bin`, make it executable and add that directory to your `$PATH`.

Comment: extra-alternatively, `cd /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/` before running the `set`

Comment: I like absolute paths ;-) Makes working with e.g. history so much easier. Would not matter in this case, is just a general habit.

Comment: added this to the script. Let's clean the comments =)